# Mono Cecil, method and instruction insertion

Tags: c#, mono

I have problems while adding a method and populating it with instructions. I found the needed type, added method with no issues but when I add call to WriteLine it doesn't work.

```
    foreach (TypeDefinition type in assembly.MainModule.Types)
        {
            if (type.Name == "ClassB")
            {
                //TypeReference returntype = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(void));
                MethodDefinition met = new MethodDefinition("Test", 
                    MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Static, 
                    assembly.MainModule.TypeSystem.Void);
                type.Methods.Add(met);

                ILProcessor worker = met.Body.GetILProcessor();
                Instruction msg = worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello!");
                MethodReference writeline = assembly.MainModule.Import(typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) }));
                met.Body.Instructions.Insert(0, msg);
                met.Body.Instructions.Insert(1, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, writeline));
            }
```

When I decompile the code I get "// ISSUE: unable to decompile the method." in the method body (I'm using dotPeek). Adding the call to already existing method in assembly works perfectly fine - it's visible and executing correctly. It doesn't throw any errors while running.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this [GitHub rep](https://github.com/markusschweitzer/ILRewriter) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your method is void, you should insert a `OpCodes.Ret` instruction just before the end of your method, like this:

```
...
met.Body.Instructions.Insert(0, msg);
met.Body.Instructions.Insert(1,
    Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, writeline));
met.Body.Instructions.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
```

Comment: Indeed, this one line made it work. Thank you very much for the help.